Are small analog signals more or less susceptible to interference with a DC offset applied?
Per the title--when looking at analog instrumentation signals ("AC" for this purpose) traveling over a cable (in the realm of say 1-2Vpp) are those signals more or less likely to be impacted by RF/powerline and other radiated interference with or without a DC offset?

Do you mean analogue signals that have a DC offset or, do you mean interference with a DC offset?

Correct--Are analog signals, with an applied DC offset, more likely to be impacted by radio interference than an analog signal that has no DC offset?

@Matt001 The universe cannot observe the DC offset as there is no such thing as an absolute frame of reference for such. However, if taken as a matter of a specific circuit implementation, then the specific circuit itself matters. For example, if the DC offset leads to leakage currents through a PN junction barrier which destroys charge effects over any meaningful distance, then shot noise due to that current would be added in quadrature. Also, burying a small signal underneath a large DC offset may yield other important problems to solve. But details matter.

Yes? I'm not sure how useful an answer you are expecting, given the loose question. Perhaps you could narrow this down to an example system including at least a partial schematic of the source, load, a diagram of the cable connection and what type, where the interference might be induced, and the signal and interference bandwidth or spectrum.

It wasn't immediately clear to me if by virtue of some physics that this would be an obvious answer or not. Forgive the lack of details. For sake of question I am following this precision fullwave rectifier: https://wiki.analog.com/university/courses/alm1k/circuits1/alm-cir-precision-rectifier
However, instead of using 0V reference, I am using 2.5V reference with a maximum supply of +5.0V to eliminate negative voltages. The end-processing unit doesn't care about DC offset. But I am wondering if I can help eliminate RF interference by clamping the rectified waveform back to 0V instead of 2.5

Other things being equal, a DC offset is completely irrelevant. How or why that DC got there might make other things unequal - like being noisy, or leaking noisily to/from somewhere, changing the line's impedance, or reducing the range available on an amplifier or ADC. Details matter.
